# How to delete elements from array that are at indexes in another array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays, one with data and one with indexes. I want to know if there are some good ways to delete the elements in `data` at the position given in `indexes`. I could do simple iteration but I am wondering what the shortest way is:

```
data = ['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c']
indexes = [2,5,8]

//some code here
```

Elements in `data` are gone when the indexes happened to coincide with numbers in array indexes. It should look like this:

```
['a','b','a','b','a','b']
```

Comment: Just a coincidence we're removing all the `c`'s in here?

Comment: yep thats demonstration

Comment: Poll: should [Array#delete_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_at) be changed from `delete_at(i)` to `delete_at(*i)`?

Answer (score 5):

```
data.values_at(*data.each_index.to_a - indexes)
# => ["a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"]
```

Comment: No one can find a better solution than this. great answer.

Comment: This is actually perfect.

Answer (score 4):

I will do as below:

```
data = ['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c']
indexes = [2,5,8]
data.values_at(*(0...data.size).to_a - indexes)
# => ["a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"]
```

Comment: @sawa I feel good that we thought same way... :) But you were fast.

Comment: This is a really good answer, but it should be noted that behind the scenes array subtraction uses iteration.

Answer (score 4):

*Doing it without iteration might seem like a good goal, but iteration done right is going to be extremely fast.*

Benchmarks are important:

```
require 'benchmark'

DATA = ['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c']
INDEXES = [2,5,8]

def ttm(data)
  d2 = data.dup
  INDEXES.sort.reverse.each{ |i| d2.delete_at(i) }
  d2
end

def devon_parsons(data)
  new_data = data.each_with_index.reject do |value,index|
    INDEXES.include? index
  end.map(&:first)
  new_data
end

def arup_rakshit(data)
  data.values_at(*(0...data.size).to_a - INDEXES)
end

def sawa(data)
  data.values_at(*data.each_index.to_a - INDEXES)
end
```

Make sure it's an apples to apples test:

```
ttm(DATA)           # => ["a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"]
devon_parsons(DATA) # => ["a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"]
arup_rakshit(DATA)  # => ["a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"]
sawa(DATA)          # => ["a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"]
```

Run the benchmarks:

```
n = 100_000 
Benchmark.bm(13) do |b|
  b.report('ttm:')          { n.times { ttm(DATA)           } }
  b.report('devon_parsons') { n.times { devon_parsons(DATA) } }
  b.report('arup_rakshit')  { n.times { arup_rakshit(DATA)  } }
  b.report('sawa')          { n.times { sawa(DATA)          } }
end
```

Which results in:

```
# >>                     user     system      total        real
# >> ttm:            0.130000   0.000000   0.130000 (  0.127559)
# >> devon_parsons   0.530000   0.000000   0.530000 (  0.535929)
# >> arup_rakshit    0.250000   0.000000   0.250000 (  0.255295)
# >> sawa            0.300000   0.010000   0.310000 (  0.305376)
```

If the data size grows:

```
DATA2 = DATA * 100
Benchmark.bm(13) do |b|
  b.report('ttm:')          { n.times { ttm(DATA2)           } }
  b.report('devon_parsons') { n.times { devon_parsons(DATA2) } }
  b.report('arup_rakshit')  { n.times { arup_rakshit(DATA2)  } }
  b.report('sawa')          { n.times { sawa(DATA2)          } }
end
```

The results really change:

```
# >>                     user     system      total        real
# >> ttm:            0.320000   0.090000   0.410000 (  0.420074)
# >> devon_parsons  39.170000   0.080000  39.250000 ( 39.265062)
# >> arup_rakshit    9.950000   0.010000   9.960000 (  9.975699)
# >> sawa            9.940000   0.020000   9.960000 (  9.959036)
```

It's really important to test what happens as the array size changes. What might run quickly on a small array can slow dramatically as the array grows. And, too often, what seems like a cool way to do something turns out to be very slow because there are hidden costs. Benchmarks help us figure these things out.

Note: Using `sort.reverse` is very important. Without those the array will be mangled.

---

> sort can further be improved to sort_by(&:itself)

```
require 'benchmark'

array = (0..99).to_a.shuffle
n = 100_000 

Benchmark.bm(7) do |b|
  b.report('sort:')    { n.times { array.sort              } }
  b.report('sort_by:') { n.times { array.sort_by(&:itself) } }
end
```

Resulting in:

```
              user     system      total        real
sort:     0.460000   0.010000   0.470000 (  0.480236)
sort_by:  3.600000   0.030000   3.630000 (  3.627871)
```

Increasing the array size:

```
array = (0..999).to_a.shuffle
Benchmark.bm(13) do |b|
  b.report('sort:')    { n.times { array.sort              } }
  b.report('sort_by:') { n.times { array.sort_by(&:itself) } }
end
```

Resulting in:

```
                    user     system      total        real
sort:           9.520000   0.120000   9.640000 (  9.659246)
sort_by:       53.530000   0.720000  54.250000 ( 54.321285)
```

Comment: Enlightening.   Thanks!

Comment: I have a solution, which seems to perform better - is it really better or fluke?

Comment: Told you mine was in N^2 time :P

Comment: If you only care about performance, `sort` can further be improved to `sort_by(&:itself)`.

Comment: `sort` will run faster than `sort_by` when comparing basic objects like numbers. See the added benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_data = data.each_with_index.reject do |value,index|
  indexes.include? index
end.map(&:first)
```

New answer that actually works this time - it runs in O(n^2) and I don't see a way of doing it without iterating over indexes at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
data = ['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c']
indexes = [2,5,8]

updated_data = data.dup
indexes.each { |i| updated_data[i] = nil}
updated_data.compact!
p updated_data # Prints ["a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"]
```

As far as benchmark goes, using the Tin Man's code, it seems to perform the best.  Not sure whether it has something to do with small size of `indexes` array.

```
                    user     system      total        real
ttm:            0.125000   0.000000   0.125000 (  0.113075)
devon_parsons   0.484000   0.000000   0.484000 (  0.491327)
arup_rakshit    0.219000   0.000000   0.219000 (  0.221149)
sawa            0.250000   0.000000   0.250000 (  0.253168)
wandmaker       0.094000   0.016000   0.110000 (  0.095063)

# Run 2 with larger data
                    user     system      total        real
ttm:            0.422000   0.188000   0.610000 (  0.596413)
devon_parsons  39.328000   0.000000  39.328000 ( 39.489394)
arup_rakshit   10.078000   0.562000  10.640000 ( 10.644099)
sawa           10.219000   0.110000  10.329000 ( 10.328250)
wandmaker       0.359000   0.062000   0.421000 (  0.423282)
```

Comment: What if the OPs array contained nils that were significant? You'd be removing data not specified by `indexes`. You need code to guard against that.

Comment: @theTinMan Yeah, that makes sense.